# Why does mechanize raise NoMethodError on my page2.links.each method chain?

Tags: ruby, loops, hyperlink, mechanize, nomethoderror

### Error

```
mySpiderScript.rb:119:in ` block (3 levels) in <main>': undefined method `links' for #<Mechanize::Image:0x120a7e38> (NoMethodError)
```

### Code

```
agent2 = Mechanize.new
page2 = agent2.get('http://www.mywebsite.net')
  page2.links.each do |link2|     #line 119
    name = link2.href.to_s
```

How do I fix this so that the script keeps running?

### Update

Here is what page2.body returns.

```
����JFIF���ICC_PROFILE�lcms0mntrRGB XYZ �*acspAPPL���-lcms
                                                                                   desc8cprt@Nwtpt�chad�,rXYZ�bXYZ�gXYZ�rTRC
                                                                                                                                        gTRC, bTRCL chrml$mluc
                                                                                                                                                                  enUSsRGB built-inmluc
                                                                                                                                                                                          enUS2No copyright, use freelyXYZ ���-sf32
Y�                     J����*��������������XYZ o�8��XYZ $����XYZ b����paraff��
Y�raff��
Y�raff��
[chrm��T{L���&f\��





 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C          


2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222��"����������
                                                                                         ?����
```

Comment: I get `NameError: undefined local variable or method `agent2' for main:Object` when I run your code because you didn't post a [mcve]. I would have hoped that after asking 66 questions one would know [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: Make sure *page2* is a valid mechanize object and not nil.

Comment: @CodeGnome: the body is not a valid mechanize object. How to skip it? since i don't have HTML element to use.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431211/how-to-fix-this-undefined-method-links-for-mechanizeimage0x120a7e38-no?noredirect=1#comment66207827_39431211):

> [T]he body is not a valid mechanize object. How to skip it?

There are lot of ways to validate your object before trying to invoke a method on it. One way is to use the poorly-documented [safe navigation operator](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537) (`&.`) introduced in Ruby 2.3.0. For example, using your existing code:

```
page2&.links&.each do |link2|
```

This will return nil if the object in *page2* doesn't respond to #links, or the result of `page2.links` doesn't respond to #each. Program flow will then continue after the #each block formed by your `page2&.links&.each` method chain.

Comment: That's a strange way to do it. Maybe checking if `page2.is_a? Mechanize::Page` is better.